# Given a key, find command that Emacs binds by default

Tags: key-bindings, help

If I've created custom keybindings, possibly overriding some Emacs default keybindings, is there a way to determine what command a given key would be bound to by default (i.e. if I hadn't overridden that key's binding)?

For example, I'm running Doom Emacs, but trying to follow along with a tutorial that was written for a more vanilla Emacs setup. The tutorial will mention a key to type, without mentioning the intended command.

Comment: You can try opening another Emacs session without your init file: `emacs -Q`, and using `C-h k` to see what the default binding is. If you mean what key is bound by default in some particular situation/setup other than your init file, then put that session in that situation/setup before using `C-h k`. There may be another, more direct way, but this is probably what I would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an answer of the comment I added, as I don't see any other answers, so far.

You can try opening another Emacs session without your init file: `emacs -Q`, and using `C-h k` to see what the default binding is.

If you mean what key is bound by default in some particular situation/setup other than your init file, then put that session in that situation/setup before using `C-h k`.

There may be another, more direct way, but this is probably what I would do.